# Vue: Best way to submit form of child component from the parent component through method

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-props

I have 2 components.

Parent Component:

```
 Vue.component('parent', {
              template: '<div><child :counter="counter" :isSubmit="isSubmit" showButton="true"></child>'+
              '<button v-on:click="changeCounter">Change Counter</button></div>',
              data () {
                return {
                    counter: 2,
                    isSubmit : false
                }
              },
              methods : {
                changeCounter () {
                    //retrieve value of counter dynamically let's say through ajax call.
                    this.counter = 9;
                    this.isSubmit = true;
                }
              }
            })
```

Child Component:

```
Vue.component('child', {
          template: '<form action="test.php" method="GET" ref="childForm">'+
          '<input type="hidden" v-model="counter" name="counter" />'+
          '<input type="submit" v-if="showButton" /></form>',
          props: {
            counter : {
                type: Number,
                default: 0
            },
            showButton:false,
            isSubmit: false
          },
          watch : {
            isSubmit (val) {
                   console.log("Inside watcher");
                    this.submitForm();
            }
          },
          methods : {
            submitForm () {
                console.log(this.counter);// output-9
                this.$refs.childForm.submit();
            },
         
          }

        })
```

index.html

```
....
<div id="app>">
   <parent></parent>
   <parent></parent>
</div>
....
```

In this example, When I click on the "Change Counter" button, the form is submitted with the older value of the counter (i.e. submitted to /test.php?counter=2). Although props of child component are reactive in dev tools (counter = 9) it does not reflect while submitting the form. But it really works if I submit the form by the submit button on the child component (i.e. submitted to /test.php?counter=9).

Your help is appreciated. Please help me to understand why this kind of behaviour is shown and also seeking the solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do your child components have submit buttons if the submit signal comes from the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Quick note

Since you're using GET requests, you could skip the whole `<form>` thing and just go directly to the URL

```js
methods: {
  changeCounter () {
    this.counter = 9
    window.location = `test.php?counter=${this.counter}`
  }
}
```

---

#### Longer answer

You need to wait for the `counter` change to update the DOM in order to use a normal form submission.

To wait for state changes to effect the DOM, use `$nextTick`. I would also advise submitting the form via the `submitForm` method rather than watching a Boolean value. You can access the method by using refs.

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: `<form action="test.php" method="GET" ref="childForm">
    <input type="hidden" :value="counter" name="counter" />
    <input type="submit" v-if="showButton" />
  </form>`,
  props: {
    counter : {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    },
    showButton: Boolean
  },
  methods: {
    async submitForm () {
      await this.$nextTick() // wait for the DOM to update
      this.$refs.childForm.submit()
    }
  }
})
```

```js
Vue.component("parent", {
  template: `<div>
    <child :counter="counter" :show-button="true" ref="form"></child>
    <button @click="changeCounter">Change Counter</button>
  </div>`,
  data: () => ({ counter: 2 }),
  methods: {
    changeCounter () {
      this.counter = 9
      this.$refs.form.submitForm() // call the child component method
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I get `submitForm()` is not a method

Comment: @Phil without seeing your code, I cannot provide any advice other than to make sure you're using the `ref` properly. FYI, if you're assigning `ref="form"` attributes within a `v-for` loop, keep in mind that `this.$refs.form` will be an array. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements